# Z sorting implementation for a 2D isometric game

Tags: c#, sorting, coordinate-system, unity3d

This is a naive implementation of a Z-sorting in order to fake 3D depth using sprites in a 2D scene. I would appreciate feedback on this, especially for performance as this has to be called each frame to handle moving objects.

A ZIndexHandler is added to every object that may need to be sorted. When an object is loaded in the scene, `OnEnable` is automatically called by Unity3D. When the object is removed or hidden, `OnDisable` is called.

Each object registers and unregisters itself from the ZIndexManager depending on whether it needs to get sorted on not.

```
public class ZIndexHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    //A transform is used to place the position offset of the object
    //So that PositionOnScreen is not the middle of the sprite
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform positionOnScreenTransform;
    public Transform PositionOnScreenTransform
    {
        set { positionOnScreenTransform = value; }
        get { return positionOnScreenTransform; }
    }

    public Vector3 PositionOnScreen
    {
        get { return positionOnScreenTransform.position; }
    }

    //If true, this object won't get sorted.
    [SerializeField]
    private bool ignoreZBuffer;
    public bool IgnoreZBuffer
    {
        get { return ignoreZBuffer; }
        set
        {
            ignoreZBuffer = value;
            if(!ignoreZBuffer)
                updateHandlerActivy(true);
        }
    }

    //Pointer to the ZIndexManager singleton
    private ZIndexManager indexManagerInstance;

    //The sprites in this objects are all stored here once and for all
    protected List<SpriteRenderer> sprites;

    protected virtual void Awake()
    {
        sprites = new List<SpriteRenderer>();

        //Recursively search for sprite in the object's hierarchy
        findAndStoreSpritesRecursive(transform);
    }

    void OnEnable()
    {
        indexManagerInstance = ZIndexManager.Instance;
        updateHandlerActivy(!ignoreZBuffer);
    }

    void OnDisable()
    {
        updateHandlerActivy(false);
    }

    //Register or unregister this object to the Z-sorting process
    private void updateHandlerActivy(bool needSort)
    {
        if (indexManagerInstance)
        {
            if(needSort)
                indexManagerInstance.registerObject(this);
            else
                indexManagerInstance.removeObject(this);
        }
    }

    private void findAndStoreSpritesRecursive(Transform curTransform)
    {
        SpriteRenderer sr = curTransform.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        if (sr != null)
            sprites.Add(sr);
        foreach (Transform t in transform)
            findAndStoreSpritesRecursive(t);
    }

    public void setZIndex(int index)
    {
        foreach (SpriteRenderer s in sprites)
            s.sortingOrder = index;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        return GetInstanceID() == ((ZIndexHandler)other).GetInstanceID();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

The ZIndexManager class is a singleton that handles the sorting.

```
public class ZIndexManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    List<ZIndexHandler> screenObjects = new List<ZIndexHandler>();

    //The Z index starts at 10 to leave some space for the background
    public static int StartIndex = 10;

    //Singleton implementation using FindObjectOfType
    private static ZIndexManager instance;
    public static ZIndexManager Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = FindObjectOfType<ZIndexManager>();
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public void registerObject(ZIndexHandler obj)
    {
        screenObjects.Add(obj);
    }

    public void removeObject(ZIndexHandler obj)
    {
        if(screenObjects.Contains(obj))
            screenObjects.Remove(obj);
    }

    public void sortZBufferOnList(ref List<ZIndexHandler> list)
    {
        //Put everything in the correct order based on the Y position of the object
        list.Sort(delegate (ZIndexHandler zi1, ZIndexHandler zi2)
        {
            if(zi1 && ! zi2)
                return -1;
            else if(!zi1)
                return 1;

            Vector3 p1 = zi1.PositionOnScreen;
            Vector3 p2 = zi2.PositionOnScreen;
            if (p1.y == p2.y) return 0;
            return -1 * p1.y.CompareTo(p2.y);
        });

        //Iterate over each object to update their Z index
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
            list[i].setZIndex(StartIndex + i);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        sortZBufferOnList(ref screenObjects);
    }
}
```